# HibernateTemplate().update(object) doesn't update the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I'm using the following method to update an object but it doesn't do anything. Strangely, it doesn't throw any error too.

```
public void updateObject(Object object) {
    getHibernateTemplate().update(object);
}
```

I'm using a mapped composite-id like the following:

```
<composite-id class="com.company.project.model.ObjectPK" mapped="true">
    <key-property name="col1" type="string" column="COL1"/>
    <key-property name="col2" type="string" column="COL2"/>
</composite-id>
<property name="col3" type="string" column="COL3"/>
```

I read somewhere that I need to fetch the object before trying to update it. Is that what I need to do here?

Comment: Please show your transaction boundaries. You may also need to see the generated sql and if there are any exception being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateOperations.html#update%28java.lang.Object%29) states that you can update a "given [persistent](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview) instance" this way, so you need to fetch the object first and operate on the returned instance.

Comment: Your suggestion pointed me to the problem. In my particular case, I ended up using the `HibernateTemplate.merge()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Updates don't work in isolation. You have to be within a transaction. Since you didn't mention anything about them, I'd guess you aren't [managing your transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) properly.